# Why doesn't Boole return 0?

Tags: evaluation, boolean-computation

I'm writing a code to evaluate  if the *Cauchy-Riemann conditions* are satisfied for a given function. For example, for the function `f[z]=Conjugate[E^(z)]` it has to evaluate this expression below

```
Boole[E^x Cos[y] == -E^x Cos[y]]
```

But it doesn't give a zero output. It just holds unevaluated.
I don't understand why

Comment: Why don't you just check the relation holds by SameQ?

Comment: In short: `Boole` doesn't evaluate because its argument is neither literal `True` nor literal `False`.  `==` doesn't evaluate to True/False because 1) the result would depend on the parameters `x` and `y` 2) even if it didn't, `==` doesn't automatically check not-entirely-trivial cases

Comment: You might know something about what `x` and `y` are (reals, complexes, etc.), but *Mathematica* does not unless you tell it. So, `E^x Cos[y] == -E^x Cos[y]` remains unevaluated, and `Boole[]` thus also remains unevaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is that in general this expression can either be true or false, depending on values of `y`. When `Cos[y]==0`the expression is true.

i.e. Try `Boole[Simplify[E^x Cos[y] == -E^x Cos[y], 0 < y < \[Pi]/2]]`

Answer (score 0):

Because it is `SameQ (===)` that guarantees a binary outcome of `True` and `False`, rather than `Equal (==)`.

```
Boole[E^x Cos[y] === -E^x Cos[y]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

Comment: While `SameQ` guarantees a boolean outcome, be aware of the fact that it checks if the two expressions are literally identical or not, i.e. it performs a structural check and not a semantic one. It might work in some cases, but not in all which otherwise should return `True` in a mathematical sense, e.g. `0 === 0.0`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes it is. But it answers the why, which is what is being asked.

Comment: See Szabolcs's comment above: the mathematical truth value only makes sense if we assume something about the parameters - which `SameQ` ignores entirely. Compare these: `(E^x Cos[y] === -E^x Cos[y]) /. y -> Pi/2` returns `False` while `(E^x Cos[y] == -E^x Cos[y]) /. y -> Pi/2` returns `True`. While your approach works here, it is not general enough and is not guaranteed to return the mathematically sensible value. On the other hand, if one wants a structural comparison, then it is of course fine. I had the impression that OP wanted a logical comparison instead of a structural one.